# How to Rescale Hover Menu.

Tags: html, css

Hello I have problem rescaling a hover menu correctly and so that everyone knows what i mean i have then made this 1:19 min video to illustrate my problem.

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sYdmjivW2A&feature=youtu.be

Relavant Html Code:

```
<div id="HoverMenu">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li><form action="HomeDanish.html" method="get"><input id="Denmark" type="image" src="Denmark.png"></form>
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li><form action="HomeEnglish.html" method="get"><input id="England" type="image" src="England.png"></form></li>
            <li><form action="HomeGerman.html" method="get"><input id="Germany" type="image" src="Germany.png"></form></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My relavant css code:

```
#Logo{
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 19.32%;
top: 4.5vw;
left: 4.7vw;

}


* { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#HoverMenu{ 
position: absolute;
top:0.5vw;
left:27vw;
width: 4.5%;
height: auto;
}

#HoverMenu > ul > li {
position: relative; 
background: transparent;
display: inline-block;
}

#HoverMenu ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
background: transparent;
}

#HoverMenu ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

I know i have Id on my input flags but they haven't been used in my css document and I have tried to use that Id and scale the flags in that way. But without luck.

Thank you for any contributions in advance!

Comment: Questions must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  You haven't explained what **"scaling"** you are referring to since there is no such CSS in your provided code. Videos really aren't much help. **Demos reproducing the issue are preferred**

Comment: I am pretty sure i am saying that i need my HoverMenu to scale like my Logo Image is. And i have given you code that shows how my Logo scales and how i am trying to get my hovermenu to scale in the same way but that doesn't work.

Comment: What **scaling** are you referring to? `scale` is a css property and you aren't using it. That's why a **demo** is so important.

Comment: I am referring to the width and height that i have set to % and therefore it scales when i resize the window. When i say scale i am not referring to the css property scale. I am referring to the common verb "scale" used by common people.

Comment: But you're asking web developers questions so using the correct term is important. So you mean **responsiveness** I guess. So now, please clearly explain what the actual problem is. If the video link were to fail, it would not be clear to future users what the actual problem is. ...at the moment *it is not clear*.

Comment: I dont know how i can put it any clearer but i will try... 

#HoverMenu{ 
position: absolute;
top:0.5vw;
left:27vw;
width: 4.5%;
height: auto;
}

It does not do what i ask when it comes to width and height. Although it does work when i use this code on a reqular <img> but not when i do it on a <div><ul><li></li></ul></div>

Comment: So far every video based question i have asked has been solved within an hour. but far from every question asked in writing has been solved.

There is a saying: "A picture describes more than a 1000 words" Imagine how many words a 30 fps video can describe then. 

And by the way did you know that in chinese the word "liang" can mean a 100 different things but yet every day 1.4 billion chinese people takes out of context which liang the speaker is referring to. 

Thank you though for even taking a look at my question posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add the CSS to the input element, since that's the item that needs resizing..

```
#HoverMenu ul li form input
{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2kxw2ue/1/)

Comment: Thank you sir! This does what i want. But now it is my positioning that makes my flags go outside its frame when i resize but i guess thats another problem. 

Thanks!